# name matching with escape sequence in commons dbutils

Tags: sql, java-8, apache-commons-dbutils

I am using dbutils QueryRunner on a product table to get (ID, Name)  from the table where the query is as follows:

```
select ID, NAME
from PRODUCT
where NAME LIKE ?
LIMIT 5;
```

I am getting

> ERROR 203 (22005): Type mismatch. BOOLEAN for null Query

while if i run the same query with `NAME = ?` , it works fine.

Can you please let me know what is wrong with the syntax and also how can i use the escape sequence for e.g

`WHERE NAME LIKE 'XYZ%'`

Comment: SQL usually requires `LIKE` followed by a string in single quotes.  Does your example of `WHERE NAME LIKE 'XYZ%'` work?  If so, what else are you asking?

Comment: `List<Map<String, Object>> results =  new QueryRunner(getDataSource()).query(
                    Query, new MapListHandler(), "'"+productName+"%'");`


that is how i am calling my function when i get the error; No the example dosent work!

Comment: There is no unified SQL parser in JDBC. How your SQL statement is parsed and where and how `?` works is up to the particular driver and/or database. To my experience, inexplicable limitations are the norm…